# Facebook Messenger Bot verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I submitted my facebook messenger bot for app review and the rejection reason was "*received no response*".

I've tested my bot from my own account and some other testers that I added to my facebook app for testing.
However, when I try to test using the default `Open Graph Test User` I don't get any response. The Send Message API fails with error:

```
{"error": {"message":"(#100) No matching user found", "type":"OAuthException", ...}}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I send message to test users using the Send/Receive message API?

Comment: Got the same issue. When requesting the user profile API, I got this answer: `(#100) No matching user found`. And when I want to send a message to this test user I got this _weird_ answer `(#551) This person isn't receiving messages from you right now`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and got responses in the facebook developers community. It seems like it is confirmed bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/230322797329131/?hc_location=ufi

Update:
It seems to work now. Since Tuesday this week I can see reviewers sending messages to the bot and get responses in the messages of the page.

Comment: How do you get your bot verified from fb if this bug exists? I do see new bots coming up on facebook. Any idea how they're getting verified?

Comment: It seems to be working now...for me since Tuesday. I could see in my pages messages that guys from california were writing with my bot. unfortunately they didnt like the experience (was a bot I then just submitted to test the review process; my main bot is in german and they seem to have problems reviewing bots in other languages; but thats a different story ;-) )

Answer (score 6):

My problem was

I am sending **recipient id** *instead* **sender id** in my json data.

```
dict_to_send = {
   'message': {'text': u'hello FB'},
   'recipient': {'id': **'*sender_id_here*'**}
}
res = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=your_token_here", <br>data=json.dumps(dict_to_send), headers = {'content-type':'application/json'})
```

Comment: Also my problem. I think facebook demo app uses recipient.id instead of sender.id

Answer (score 0):

The FB application webhooks should be subscribed only for the following events:

- messages
- messaging_postbacks

subscribing to one of the others events might throw that exception.

source here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/578746852290927/?hc_location=ufi

Answer (score -6):

Answers below:

1) You shouldn't submit for App Review without testing to see if your stuff works.

2) I'm guessing you used the user ID from the Test User interface. If you read the docs more closely, you'll see that the user IDs used for Messenger Platform is different than user IDs you get from Facebook Login (which is what the test user interface shows). Read the "Send/Receive API" section under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#send_message

Comment: I did already try that, but in vain. It does work for regular facebook users (which is the reason i submitted the app and explains your #1 comment). I'm only facing issues for test users that facebook would use to verify my integration (like `Open Graph Test User`).